# Scala typed trait different types Implementation keeping it in Map, not working

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is there any better design to achieve this scenario?

```
case class Animal()
case class Dog() extends Animal
case class Cow() extends Animal

trait BasePropertyImpl[T <: Animal] {
  def property1(animal: T): T

  def property2(animal: T): T
}

object DogPropertyImpl extends BasePropertyImpl[Dog] {
  def property1(animal: Dog): Dog = ???

  def property2(animal: Dog): Dog = ???
}

object CowPropertyImpl extends BasePropertyImpl[Cow] {
  def property1(animal: Cow): Cow = ???

  def property2(animal: Cow): Cow = ???
}

object AnimalImplRegistrar {
  def getRegisteredAnimals: Map[String, BasePropertyImpl[Animal]] = Map(
    "Dog" -> DogPropertyImpl,
    "Cow" -> CowPropertyImpl,
  )
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val animal = AnimalImplRegistrar.getRegisteredAnimals.get("Dog").get
    aminal.property1(Dog())
  }
}
```

Here what I am trying to achieve is deferent implementation say CowPropertyImpl, DogPropertyImpl , or some more different implementations, I am keeping it in a Map and in runtime based on user input I am retrieving the implementation from Map and calling the method of that Impl class

Comment: Did you have a look at: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html? Other than that your code doesn't compile for other reasons too. Case class inheritance isn't possible and the last call to propery1 doesn't have a parameter. What exactly is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: thanks for the quick response, yes I have looked into the scala variances page.
Here what I am trying to achieve is deferent implementation say CowPropertyImpl,  DogPropertyImpl , or some more different implementation I would keep it in Map and in runtime based on user input I would retrieve the implementation from Map and call the method of that Impl class

Answer (score 3):

This is a good candidate for the [Type Class Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class):

```
sealed trait Animal
case object Dog extends Animal
case object Cat extends Animal

trait AnimalProperties[A] {
  def property: A
} 

object AnimalProperties {
  implicit val dogProperties = new AnimalProperties[Dog.type] {
    override def property: Dog.type = ???
  }

  implicit val catProperties = new AnimalProperties[Cat.type] {
    override def property: Cat.type = ???
  }
}

def f[A](a: A)(implicit ev: AnimalProperties[A]) = {
  val a: A = ev.property
}
```

Based on the type of `A` (cat, dog) we get the desired properties of each animal.

Comment: How can I achieve calling this runtime with different types? for example, if there is a rest API, something like /Dog/123 or /Cat/123, now if I have to call your solution based on the rest API, how do I call it? given that  Dog or Cat considered as path variable.

Comment: @Imran Dynamic dispatch using strings doesn't really match the purpose of the pattern. If that's the case, we'll need another strategy.